# How can I convert datetime from Flask to Highcharts

Tags: python, datetime, highcharts

I use Flask for my web page. Now I want to create a page to generate a spline chart, so I chose Highcharts.

From Flask, it returns data like this:

> data = [[datetime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0), 20],[datetime(2015, 10, 2, 0,
>   0), 19],[datetime(2015, 10, 3, 0, 0), 18],[datetime(2015, 10, 4, 0,
>   0), 21],[datetime(2015, 10, 5, 0, 0), 22],...]

and in the web page, the Highchart code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#container').highcharts({
...
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%e. %b',
                year: '%b'
            }
        },
...
series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2008-2009',
            data: {{data}}
        }]
...
</script>
```

There is nothing on the web page. When I checked the html code, it appears like this:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2008-2009',
            data: [[datetime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0), 20],[datetime(2015, 10, 2, 0, 0), 19],[datetime(2015, 10, 3, 0, 0), 18],[datetime(2015, 10, 4, 0, 0), 21],[datetime(2015, 10, 5, 0, 0), 22],...]
        }]
```

When I compare with the right ones, I found that every datetime type parameter are shown like Date.UTC(2015,10,1).

How can I convert the datetime type from python to Highcharts?

Comment: Highchart drew the chart well, but it seems that highchart cannot recognize the timestamp well. I put date in the data, but it shows time which is not relevant to the date. what is the problem?

Comment: This is UNIX timestamp ? If yes then try to multiply all timestamps by 1000.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, yes I found this as well, thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in the highcharts you need to use a timestamp (time in miliseconds), so in your backend you also should take care about returning time in correct format. If not possible, you can convert time in javascript in preprocessing and then use that in highcharts. UNIX timestamps should be multiplied by 1000, to achieve javascript timestamps.